# Is the degree of a differential equation 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sqrt {1-y^2}}{y}
$$
what is the degree of the above differential equation?

A textbook ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEvgu.png)) says the degree of the above differential equation is 0. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is the differential equation of the first order.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov: Yes, but order and degree are [different things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation#Equation_order_and_degree).

Comment: But the equation is not remotely a polynomial. Or if only the highest derivative counts, it is a very simple polynomial of degree one, it has the form $c_1(x,y)y'+c_0(x,y)=0$.

Comment: The textbook is Basic Engineering Mathematics of Hanbit Publishing Network, Inc. in South Korea. [link](https://www.hanbit.co.kr/store/books/look.php?p_code=B6678975190) The author of the textbook is a professor emeritus Ma of Jeonbuk National University. [link](https://math.jbnu.ac.kr/math/10959/subview.do)